# How to distinguish string from integer in Variant Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I need to tell if variant Array element is a number as string or number as integer. When I run this sub:

```
Public Sub arrTest1()

    Dim fldValues() As Variant

    fldValues = Array("1", 1)
        
    For i = LBound(fldValues) To UBound(fldValues)
        Debug.Print fldValues(i), IsNumeric(fldValues(i))
    Next i

End Sub
```

I get this result in immediate window:

```
1             True
 1            True
```

because of indentation I am assuming that VBA knows the difference, but both appear numeric.
How do I tell them apart?

Comment: The left-aligned is a `String`, the one with a leading space is numeric - that space is there to accommodate a `-` negative sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is [`TypeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/typename-function):

```
Debug.Print fldValues(i), TypeName(fldValues(i))
```

Output:

```
1             String
 1            Integer
```

Another (*better*) option is [`VarType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function); `VarType(fldValues(i))` would return:

```
1              8 
 1             2
```

where `8` corresponds to `vbString` and `2` corresponds to `vbInteger`.

Comment: @Monardo note that `VarType` is the superior option, by far. Avoid "stringly-typed" solutions when possible.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function for a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is a robust library which covers these awkwardnesses in VBA. So here's a starter for 10.

```
Module Types

Option Explicit

Public Const NumberTypes As String = "Byte,Currency,Date,Decimal,Double,Integer,Long,LongLong,LongPtr,Single"
    

'@Description("Returns true if the variant is empty or contains an uninitialised array")
Public Function VarEmpty(ByVal ipVariant As Variant) As Boolean

    If IsArray(ipVariant) Then
    
        VarEmpty = UBound(ipVariant) = -1
        
    Else
    
        VarEmpty = IsEmpty(ipVariant)
        
    End If
    
End Function

'@Description("Sugar for 'Is Not x = nothing'")
Public Function IsSomething(ByVal ipValue As Object) As Boolean
    IsSomething = Not ipValue Is Nothing
End Function


Public Function IsBoolean(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsBoolean = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbBoolean)
End Function

Public Function IsByte(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsByte = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbByte)
End Function

Public Function IsCurrency(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsCurrency = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbCurrency)
End Function

Public Function IsDataObject(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsDataObject = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbDataObject)
End Function

Public Function IsDate(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsDate = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbDate)
End Function

Public Function IsDecimal(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsDecimal = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbDecimal)
End Function

Public Function IsDouble(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsDouble = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbDouble)
End Function

Public Function IsInteger(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInteger = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbInteger)
End Function

Public Function IsLong(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsLong = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbLong)
End Function

Public Function IsLongLong(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsLongLong = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbLongLong)
End Function

'Public Function IsLongPtr(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
'    IsLongPtr = IsVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbLongptr)
'End Function

Public Function IsSingle(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsSingle = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbSingle)
End Function

Public Function IsString(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsString = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbString)
End Function

Public Function IsUserDefinedType(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsUserDefinedType = GetVarType(CVar(ipArgs), vbUserDefinedType)
End Function

'@Description("Returns true if the values in ipArgs() are of types listed in ipTypes")
Public Function IsOfType(ByVal ipTypes As String, ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Boolean

    IsOfType = False
    
    Dim myItem As Variant
    For Each myItem In ipArgs
    
        If InStr(ipTypes, TypeName(myItem)) = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Next
    
    IsOfType = True
    
End Function
    
Private Function GetVarType(ByVal ipArgs As Variant, ByVal ipVartype As VbVarType) As Boolean

    GetVarType = False
    
    Dim myItem As Variant
    For Each myItem In ipArgs
    
        If Not VarType(myItem) = ipVartype Then Exit Function
        
    Next
    
    GetVarType = True

End Function


End Module
```

So your code would become

```
Public Sub arrTest1()

    Dim fldValues() As Variant

    fldValues = Array("1", 1)
        
    For i = LBound(fldValues) To UBound(fldValues)
        Debug.Print fldValues(i), IsOfType(NumberType,fldValues(i))
        'Or 
        'Debug.Print fldvalues(i),IsInteger(fldValues(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any benefit from doing the like `varType(fldValues(i)) = vbString`, and I cannot see any awkwardness in there.

Comment: Not sure I understand that comment